# ASP.NET Repeater ItemCreated Event Binds the Same Item Over and Over

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a Repeater on my page. There's nothing spectacular about it.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBusiness">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col width="170px" />
                <col width="75px" />
                <col width="75px" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>                        
                <th style="text-align:left; background-color: Silver;">Business</th>
                <th style="text-align:left; background-color: Silver;">Rep</th>
                <th style="text-align:left; background-color: Silver;">City</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="scrollDiv">
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="155px" />
                    <col width="75px" />
                    <col width="75px" />
                </colgroup>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litRow" />
    </ItemTemplate>                
    <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

- The HeaderTemplate defines a table to contain the header rows, which don't scroll. It also defines the start of the content table, which is contained in a scrolling div.
- The ItemTemplate contains a single Literal control, which I fill in the codebehind with table rows (we'll get to that in a moment).
- The FooterTemplate closes the scrolling div and the table.

Note, there's nothing wrong with the layout. It's the databinding. In the codebehind, I have the following code:

```
Dim list As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Business)

list = BusinessWithAddress.Select(excludeBusKey, _
                                  searchCriteria, _
                                  contained, _
                                  Connector.GetConnectionString())

Me.rptBusiness.DataSource = list
Me.rptBusiness.DataBind()
```

Now, I can *see* that list contains many distinct businesses. Over 800 of them, in fact. The problem is that when the ItemCreated event fires, I get the same business item *every single time*.

Why?

Edit:

Forgot. This is how I inspect the item to determine it's the same item over and over again.

```
Private Sub rptBusiness_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) _
    Handles rptBusiness.ItemCreated


    Dim item = CType(e.Item.DataItem, Business)

    ' Content elided

End Sub
```

Comment: how are you generating the html for the rows? do you have some sample output?

Comment: ~ It looks like you forgot something!  `The ItemTemplate contains a single Literal control, which I fill in the codebehind with table rows (we'll get to that in a moment).`